# Parsing result from GET request in Angular

Tags: json, angular, get

I'm working with a GET request right now and when I print it out the result it says [Object object]. I'm trying to parse that object into a user class I've created with no luck. If anyone could provide advice that'd be great. My attempt is below.

```
 findUser() {
    const id = this.getCurrentUser().id;
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/' + id)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe((user: User) => {
        console.log("User retrieved is " + <User>user);
        this.user = JSON.stringify(user);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Are you getting correct response from the API? If yes, you should automatically get the parsed JSON response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map` function in `http` `get` method parses the response for you.

As per the code, `.subscribe((user: User)` is already casting the response object into `User` object so there is no need to cast it again in console log.

`this.user = JSON.stringify(user);` won't solve the problem as `JSON.stringify` method coverts the `JSON` object to stringified format.

Comment: The response is correct, but without any casting i keep getting [Object object]. It's not properly translating into my User object.

Comment: Try using `console.log("User retrieved is ", user);` in that case.

Comment: that did it! Thanks for the help.